# Android: How to end animation of a listitem using valueanimator?

Tags: animation, android, objectanimator

I am using the ValueAnimator to make one row in my list pulse from dark blue to light blue finitely. However, I need to check for a boolean when the rows load and when it gets set to false I need the view to go back to its original non-pulsing state. What is the best way of doing this?

My code is as follows -

```
if(isHighlighted(post)) {
        String titleText = title.getText().toString();
        title.setText(titleText);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        timeStamp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        highLighterStartColor = resources.getColor( R.color.active_blue );
        highLighterEndColor = resources.getColor( R.color.teal );
        ValueAnimator va = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", highLighterStartColor, highLighterEndColor);
        if(va != null) {
            va.setDuration(750);
            va.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            va.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            va.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            va.start();
        }

    } else {
        title.setTextAppearance(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.style.medium_text);
        timeStamp.setTextAppearance(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.style.timestamp_text);
}
```